# Change button background-color on clicking itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Let's say I have #button with a given background-image:url(images/some_background) and I want to change it to another background when I click it, let's say url(images/other_background).

```
        HTML

         <a id="button" ></a> 

        CSS

     display: block; 
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     background-image:url(images/other_background.png)
```

I tried this, but it doesnt work :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(){

            $('#button').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/other_background.png)');

        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

CSS

```
#button{display: block; height:100px; width:100px;  
background-image:url(http://cheeptalk.files.wordpress.com/
2009/05/smurfs-hefty-smurf-100x100.png?w=96&h=96); border:1px solid red;}
```

*border to see easier only*

code

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundImage','url(http://images.mirror.co.uk/upl/m4/\
    feb2010/9/3/mr-t-100x100-938742195.jpg)');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Lvnmw/

Obviously, you will need to switch out the images for your own.

If you are having trouble, check

1. That you are calling the jQuery script first, before this script.
2. That the path to your images is correct.

Comment: I think the specific problem he was having was related to him not preventing his hyperlinks default event. In a comment to a deleted answer he stated that he changed it to a button and it worked.

Comment: The comment above nailed it. Went back to my original code and it magically worked. One more question, how would I go about permanently changing the background image of the button, so if i reload the page the "other_background" would be there.

Comment: You could use HTML5 local storage ( http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html ) to store the state, then query that on page load?

Answer (score 0):

alittle off-topic, but you should consider using sprites instead of 2 completely seperate images.

Why? Becuase for slower connections and on certain browsers, the click event will cause a 'flicker' as the new image is being downloaded then loaded. Sprites will gaurentee the image is already loaded and so you just need to change the background-position to 'load' the new image.

Comment: Setting up sprite will require some learning. But I agree, that is the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$("#button").css("background-image", "url(/images/otherbackground.png)");

OR

$(this).css("background-image", "url(/images/otherbackground.png)");